# Very specific MySQL query I want to improve

Tags: php, mysql

This is my scenario: I have a table that contains events, every event has a field called 'created' with the timestamp in which that event was created. Now I need to sort the events from newest to oldest, but I do not want MySQL to return them all. I need only the latest in a given interval, for example in a range of 24 hours (EDIT: I'd like to have a flexible solution, not only for a 24 hours range, but maybe every few hours). And I only need for the last 10 days. I have achieved that but i'm sure in the most inefficient ways possible, that is, something like that:

```
$timestamp = time();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE ... AND `created` < '{$timestamp}' ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 1";    
    $return = $database->query( $query );

    if($database->num( $return ) > 0) {
        $event = $database->fetch( $return );
        $events[] = $event;

        $timestamp = $timestamp - 86400;
    }
}
```

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks,
Jesús.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the latest (having the greatest created date) event per day for the last 10 days.

so let's get the latest timestamp per day

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$tenDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 day'));

$innerSql = "SELECT date_format(created, '%Y-%m-%d') day, MAX(created) max_created FROM eventos WHERE date_format(created, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$today' and '$tenDaysAgo' GROUP BY date_format(created, '%Y-%m-%d')";
```

Then we can select all the events that match those created dates

```
$outerSql = "SELECT * FROM eventos INNER JOIN ($innerSql) as A WHERE eventos.created = A.max_created";
```

I haven't had a chance to test this, but the principles should be sound enough.

If you want to group by some other arbitrary number of hours you would change innerSql:

```
$fromDate = '2012-07-06' // or if you want a specific time '2012-07-06 12:00:00'
$intervalInHours = 5;
$numberOfIntervals = 10;

$innerSql = "SELECT FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, created, '$fromDate') / $intervalInHours) as grouping, MAX(created) as max_created FROM eventos WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_SUB('$fromDate', INTERVAL ($intervalInHours * $numberOfIntervals) HOUR) AND '$fromDate' GROUP BY FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, created, '$fromDate') / $intervalInHours)";
```

Comment: this solution seems to be perfect for me, but what changes I sould do if the timestamp intervals were, for example, of 5 hours instead of every day? I said one per day to simplify, thanks for your time!

Comment: Days are easier because they're naturally occurring groups in the data. You would have to create some artificial group based on your interval. You could create that with a modulus of your interval.

Comment: I've updated my response to use more than just set days. This is based off of intervals of hours from the $fromDate value.

Comment: NOTE: to avoid returning more than one row for a period, you'd need a guarantee of uniqueness on the `timestamp` column.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an index with `created` as the leading column, MySQL may be able to do a reverse scan.  If you have a 24 hour period that doesn't have any events, you could be returning a row that is NOT from that period.  To make sure you're getting a row in that period, you would really need to include a lower bound on the `created` column as well, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `eventos`
 WHERE ... 
   AND `created` <  FROM_UNIXTIME( {$timestamp} )
   AND `created` >= DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME( {$timestamp} ),INTERVAL -24 HOUR)
 ORDER BY `created` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

I think the big key to performance here is an index with `created` as the leading column, along with all (or most) of the other columns referenced in the WHERE clause, and making sure that index is used by your query.

If you need a different time interval, down to the second, this approach could be easily  generalized.

```
SELECT * FROM `eventos`
 WHERE ... 
   AND `created` <  DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL  0*{$nsecs} SECOND)
   AND `created` >= DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL -1*{$nsecs} SECOND)
 ORDER BY `created` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

From your code, it looks like the 24-hour periods are bounded at an arbitrary time... if the time function returns e.g. 1341580800 ('2012-07-06 13:20'), then your ten periods would all be from 13:20 on a given day to 13:20 the following day.

(NOTE: be sure that if your parameter is a unix timestamp integer, that this is being interpreted correctly by the database.)

It might be more efficient to pull the ten rows in a single query. If there is a guarantee that 'timestamp' is unique, then it's possible to craft such a query, but the query text will be considerably more complex than what you have now. We could mess with getting MAX(timestamp_) within each period, and then joining that back to get the row... but that's going to be really messy.

If I were going to try to pull all ten rows I would probably try going with a `UNION ALL` approach, not very pretty, but it least it could be tuned.

```
SELECT p0.*
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE ... 
            AND `created` <  DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL  0*24 HOUR)
            AND `created` >= DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL -1*24 HOUR)
          ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 1
       ) p0 
 UNION ALL           
SELECT p1.*
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE ... 
            AND `created` <  DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL -1*24 HOUR)
            AND `created` >= DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL -2*24 HOUR)
          ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 1
       ) p1 
 UNION ALL           
SELECT p2.*
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE ... 
            AND `created` <  DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL -2*24 HOUR)
            AND `created` >= DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME({$timestamp}),INTERVAL -3*24 HOUR)
          ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 1
       ) p2 
 UNION ALL           
SELECT p3.*
  FROM ...
```

Again, this could be generalized, to pass in a number of seconds as an argument. Replace HOUR with SECOND, and replace the '24' with a bind parameter that has a number of seconds.

It's rather long winded, but it should run okay.

---

Another really messy and complicated way to get this back in a single result set would be to use an inline view to get the end timestamp for the ten periods, something like this:

```
     SELECT p.period_end
       FROM (SELECT DATE_ADD(t.t_,INTERVAL -1 * i.i_* {$nsecs} SECOND) AS period_end
               FROM (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( {$timestamp} ) AS t_) t
               JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i_
                     UNION ALL SELECT 1
                     UNION ALL SELECT 2
                     UNION ALL SELECT 3
                     UNION ALL SELECT 4
                     UNION ALL SELECT 5
                     UNION ALL SELECT 6
                     UNION ALL SELECT 7
                     UNION ALL SELECT 8
                     UNION ALL SELECT 9
                    ) i
            ) p
```

And then join that to your table ...

```
  ON `created` < p.period_end
 AND `created` >= DATE_ADD(p.period_end,INTERVAL -1 * {$nsecs} SECOND)
```

And pull back MAX(created) for each period GROUP BY p.period_end, wrap that in an inline view.

And then join that back to your table to get each row.

But that is really, really messy, hard to understand, and not likely to be any faster (or more efficient) than what you are already doing.  The most improvement you could make is the time it takes to run 9 of your queries.

---

Answer (score 1):

I'd add another column that is the date(not time) and then use MySQL "group by" to get the most recent for each date.

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php/

This tutorial does just that, but by product type instead of date. This should help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, is a good solution for the problem, but what if I want the newest of every 5 hours? I'd need a more flexible solution to change interval, I said every day to simplify really, but thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all of the events within the 10 days, or just one event per day within the 10 day period?

Either way, consider [MySQL's date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for assistance. It should help you get the date range you want.

Comment: I only want the newest of every day, in a period of 10 days.

Comment: If the newest of every day for a period of 10 days is really what you want, I believe my second answer is the most correct out of all answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM eventos
     WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ORDER BY created DESC
     LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I just realized this is wrong. You want EACH DAY's newest event for the last ten days. This will just give you the most recent 10 events, going back a max of 10 days.

Comment: Or maybe it's not wrong. I'm not totally sure anymore what you're asking. Anyway, I added another answer. Hopefully one of the two is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that will get you the first event of the day for the last 10 days.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM eventos
   WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(created)
ORDER BY MAX(created) DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY DATE(created)` here is what determines the one-day interval. `DATE(created)` is just the date part of `created` without the time. So if you get the newest event (`MAX(created)`) from each day (`DATE(created)`), that gives you what you want. If you wanted an interval other than one day, I believe you'd have to somehow group by something other than `DATE(created)`.

Comment: For example, if you wanted to get the first post of each hour rather than day, you could do `GROUP BY CONCAT(DATE(created), ' ', HOUR(created))`. Basically the idea is to take `created`, round it off to the nearest <your chosen interval>, then group by that.