# How to Efficiently use SQL to Retrieve Data on Half Hour Intervals?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

**Problem - Retrieve sum of subtotals on a half hour interval efficiently**

I am using MySQL and I have a table containing subtotals with different times. I want to retrieve the sum of these sales on a half hour interval from 7 am through 12 am. My current solution (below) works but takes 13 seconds to query about 150,000 records. I intend to have several million records in the future and my current method is too slow.

How I can make this more efficient or if possible replace the PHP component with pure SQL? Also, would it help your solution to be even more efficient if I used Unix timestamps instead of having a date and time column?

**Table Name - Receipts**

```
subtotal    date        time      sale_id
--------------------------------------------
   6        09/10/2011  07:20:33     1
   5        09/10/2011  07:28:22     2
   3        09/10/2011  07:40:00     3
   5        09/10/2011  08:05:00     4
   8        09/10/2011  08:44:00     5
...............
  10        09/10/2011  18:40:00     6
   5        09/10/2011  23:05:00     7
```

**Desired Result**

An array like this:

- Half hour 1 ::: (7:00 to 7:30) => Sum of Subtotal is 11
- Half hour 2 ::: (7:30 to 8:00) => Sum of Subtotal is 3
- Half hour 3 ::: (8:00 to 8:30) => Sum of Subtotal is 5
- Half hour 4 ::: (8:30 to 9:00) => Sum of Subtotal is 8

**Current Method**

The current way uses a for loop which starts at 7 am and increments 1800 seconds, equivalent to a half hour. As a result, this makes about 34 queries to the database.

```
for($n = strtotime("07:00:00"), $e = strtotime("23:59:59"); $n <= $e; $n += 1800) {  

    $timeA = date("H:i:s", $n);
    $timeB = date("H:i:s", $n+1799);

    $query = $mySQL-> query ("SELECT SUM(subtotal)
                              FROM Receipts WHERE time > '$timeA' 
                              AND time < '$timeB'");

    while ($row = $query-> fetch_object()) {
        $sum[] = $row;
    }
}
```

**Current Output**

Output is just an array where:

- [0] represents 7 am to 7:30 am
- [1] represents 7:30 am to 8:00 am
- [33] represents 11:30 pm to 11:59:59 pm.

  array ("0" => 10000,
         "1" => 20000,
         ..............
         "33" => 5000);

Comment: @radashk The sale_id is the primary index and links to another table called sales which has the products sold per receipt. Some receipts have 3 products sold, while others have only one so I seperated it into a one to many relational database.

Comment: Index the time column. I don't see any considerable improvements else

Comment: I have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11367541/9094 which allows you to query with groups based on arbitrary time intervals, you can probably adopt it to meet your needs.

Comment: @radashk I indexed the time id like you suggested and query speed is now at 1.5 seconds. Awesome stuff buddy. While your solution is great, and I don't mean to diminish your assistance and expertise, I'm hoping for a solution that can be done through SQL alone.

Comment: If I have time later tonight, I will put together a detailed potential solution, but briefly: don't separate your date and time fields, use a single field. Unix timestamp or DATETIME, doesn't matter. That makes things easier out of the gate. You should get all your data in a single query, let mysql separate it into groups instead of using PHP. Use the date/time functions to convert your datetime field into hours and minutes, then use `GROUP BY` on those fields to group the hours/half-hours together and generate the sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this single query as well, it should return a result set with the totals in 30 minute groupings:

```
SELECT date, MIN(time) as time, SUM(subtotal) as total
FROM `Receipts`
WHERE `date` = '2012-07-30'
GROUP BY hour(time), floor(minute(time)/30)
```

To run this efficiently, add a composite index on the date and time columns.

You should get back a result set like:

```
+---------------------+--------------------+
| time                | total              |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2012-07-30 00:00:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 00:30:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 01:00:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 01:30:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 02:00:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 02:30:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 03:00:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 03:30:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 04:00:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 04:30:00 |        0.000000000 |
| 2012-07-30 05:00:00 |        0.000000000 |
| ...
+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Your query assumes that the `time` value that MySQL picks will be the min time, which assumes a natural table order sorted in time order ascending, which may not be true.  You should use min(`time`) in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @greenlion Thanks, I edited it to use `MIN` on the time column.

Comment: @greenlion Good call on the min the results returned are in proper intervals.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks for this drew, this solution is my preferred so far.

Comment: @PontusTrade Thanks, I tested it on a table of mine that had a `DATETIME` column as is reflected in my output.  Obviously your results in the `time` column will just be the times.  I just edited the query to also select the date just FYI.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would use a single DATETIME column, but using a DATE and TIME column will work.

You can do all the work in one pass using a single query:

```
select date,
       hour(`time`) hour_num, 
       IF(MINUTE(`time`) < 30, 0, 1) interval_num, 
       min(`time`) interval_begin,
       max(`time`) interval_end,
       sum(subtotal) sum_subtotal
 from receipts
where date='2012-07-31'
group by date, hour_num, interval_num;
```

Comment: I'm getting a wierd result. It outputs the sum of the subtotal on a daily interval. Pasted the array return here: http://pastebin.com/16QPzj5T

Comment: Did you accidently use 'time' (single quotes) instead of `time` (backticks)?  It looks like min(time), max(time) are returning literal values 'time'.

Comment: @greenlion Oops I used time with quotes instead of time on its own. Here's the updated array dump. I'm probably doing something wrong, but it seems that the result comes out as the subtotal per day for the given time range. http://pastebin.com/pM0mPrmr

Comment: Please post the exact SQL you ran with the result.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Since you aren't concerned with any "missing" rows, I'm also going to assume (probably wrongly) that you aren't concerned that the query might possibly return rows for periods that are not from 7AM to 12AM. This query will return your specified result set:

```
SELECT (HOUR(r.time)-7)*2+(MINUTE(r.time) DIV 30) AS i 
     , SUM(r.subtotal) AS sum_subtotal
  FROM Receipts r
 GROUP BY i
 ORDER BY i
```

This returns the period index (i) derived from an expression referencing the `time` column. For best performance of this query, you probably want to have a "covering" index available, for example:

```
ON Receipts(`time`,`subtotal`)
```

If you are going to include an equality predicate on the `date` column (which does not appear in your solution, but which does appear in the solution of the "selected" answer, then it would be good to have that column as a leading index in the "covering" index.

```
ON Receipts(`date`,`time`,`subtotal`)
```

If you want to ensure that you are not returning any rows for periods before 7AM, then you could simply add a `HAVING i >= 0` clause to the query. (Rows for periods before 7AM would generate a negative number for i.)

```
SELECT (HOUR(r.time)-7)*2+(MINUTE(r.time) DIV 30) AS i 
     , SUM(r.subtotal) AS sum_subtotal
  FROM Receipts r
 GROUP BY i
HAVING i >= 0
 ORDER BY i
```

---

**PREVIOUSLY:**

I've assumed that you want a result set similar to the one you are currently returning, but in one fell swoop. This query will return the same 33 rows you are currently retrieving, but with an extra column identifying the period (0 - 33). This is as close to your current solution that I could get:

```
SELECT t.i
     , IFNULL(SUM(r.subtotal),0) AS sum_subtotal
  FROM (SELECT (d1.i + d2.i + d4.i + d8.i + d16.i + d32.i) AS i
             , ADDTIME('07:00:00',SEC_TO_TIME((d1.i+d2.i+d4.i+d8.i+d16.i+d32.i)*1800)) AS b_time
             , ADDTIME('07:30:00',SEC_TO_TIME((d1.i+d2.i+d4.i+d8.i+d16.i+d32.i)*1800)) AS e_time
          FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION ALL SELECT 1) d1 CROSS
          JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION ALL SELECT 2) d2 CROSS
          JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION ALL SELECT 4) d4 CROSS
          JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION ALL SELECT 8) d8 CROSS
          JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION ALL SELECT 16) d16 CROSS
          JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION ALL SELECT 32) d32
        HAVING i <= 33
       ) t
  LEFT
  JOIN Receipts r ON r.time >= t.b_time AND r.time < t.e_time
 GROUP BY t.i
 ORDER BY t.i
```

Some important notes:

It looks like your current solution may be "missing" rows from Receipts whenever the the seconds is exactly equal to '59' or '00'.

It also looks like you aren't concerned with the date component, you are just getting a single value for all dates. (I may have misread that.) If so, the separation of the DATE and TIME columns helps with this, because you can reference the bare TIME column in your query.

It's easy to add a WHERE clause on the `date` column. e.g. to get the subtotal rollups for just a single day e.g. add a WHERE clause before the `GROUP BY`.

```
WHERE r.date = '2011-09-10'
```

A covering index `ON Receipts(time,subtotal)` (if you don't already have a covering index) may help with performance. (If you include an equality predicate on the date column (as in the WHERE clause above, the most suitable covering index would likely be `ON Receipts(date,time,subtotal)`.

I've made an assumption that the `time` column is of datatype TIME. (If it isn't, then a small adjustment to the query (in the inline view aliased as `t`) is probably called for, to have the datatype of the (derived) b_time and e_time columns match the datatype of the `time` column in Receipts.

Some of proposed solutions in other answers are not guaranteed to return 33 rows, when there are no rows in Receipts within a given time period. "Missing rows" may not be an issue for you, but it is a frequent issue with timeseries and timeperiod data.

I've made the assumption that you would prefer to have a guarantee of 33 rows returned. The query above returns a subtotal of zero when no rows are found matching a time period. (I note that your current solution will return a NULL in that case. I've gone and wrapped that SUM aggregate in an IFNULL function, so that it will return a 0 when the SUM is NULL.)

So, the inline query aliased as `t` is an ugly mess, but it works fast. What it's doing is generating 33 rows, with distinct integer values 0 thru 33. At the same time, it derives a "begin time" and an "end time" that will be used to "match" each period to the `time` column on the `Receipts` table.

We take care not to wrap the `time` column from the Receipts table in any functions, but reference just the bare column. And we want to ensure we don't have any implicit conversion going on (which is why we want the datatypes of b_time and e__time to match. The `ADDTIME` and `SEC_TO_TIME` functions both return `TIME` datatype. (We can't get around doing the matching and the GROUP BY operations.)

The "end time" value for that last period is returned as "24:00:00", and we verify that this is a valid time for matching by running this test:

```
SELECT MAKETIME(23,59,59) < MAKETIME(24,0,0)
```

which is successful (returns a 1) so we're good there.

The derived columns (`t.b_time` and `t.e_time`) could be included in the resultset as well, but they aren't needed to create your array, and it's (likely) more efficient if you don't include them.

---

And one final note: for optimal performance, it may be beneficial to load the inline view aliased as `t` into an actual table (a temporary table would be fine.), and then you could reference the table in place of the inline view. The advantage of doing that is that you could create an index on that table.

Comment: Hi Spencer. Your solution returns the exact results I need and the same way my current loop does. My only concern is that it still took 9 seconds to run the entire script, while the solution offered by drew at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11768140/1547373 took half a second. Maybe I'm missing something as to why it's taking this long? Also good point about missing rows when no time exists. There is enough data so that it won't be a problem however. I want to reward both answers as correct since they both are, just in different ways.

Comment: Hi Pontus. 9 seconds of elapsed time is a lot longer than I would have expected. Drew's solution involves a DATE, but the solution I have doesn't. Performance should definitely be faster, but I'd really need to review the EXPLAIN and the table definitions, including indexes. The query I provided is going to process every single one of those 150,000 rows, and assign them all into 33 "buckets". Because of the JOIN operation in this query, it's going to benefit from proper indexes.

Comment: @Pontus: I updated my answer to add a query that should return the specified result more efficiently than my previous answer. This returns the two columns: i (as the period identifier as shown in the question, and a subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it pure SQL is to use a lookup table. I don't know MySql that well so there maybe alot of improvement to the code. All my code will be Ms Sql.. 
I would do it something like this:

```
   /* Mock salesTable */
   Declare @SalesTable TABLE (SubTotal int, SaleDate datetime)
Insert into @SalesTable (SubTotal, SaleDate) VALUES (1, '2012-08-01 12:00')
Insert into @SalesTable (SubTotal, SaleDate) VALUES (2, '2012-08-01 12:10')
Insert into @SalesTable (SubTotal, SaleDate) VALUES (3, '2012-08-01 12:15')
Insert into @SalesTable (SubTotal, SaleDate) VALUES (4, '2012-08-01 12:30')
Insert into @SalesTable (SubTotal, SaleDate) VALUES (5, '2012-08-01 12:35')
Insert into @SalesTable (SubTotal, SaleDate) VALUES (6, '2012-08-01 13:00')
Insert into @SalesTable (SubTotal, SaleDate) VALUES (7, '2012-08-01 14:00')

/* input data */
declare @From datetime, @To DateTime, @intervall int 
set @from = '2012-08-01' 
set @to = '2012-08-02'
set @intervall = 30

/* Create lookup table */
DECLARE @lookup TABLE (StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime) 
DECLARE @tmpTime datetime
SET @tmpTime = @from
WHILE (@tmpTime <= @To) 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @lookup (StartTime, EndTime) VALUES (@tmpTime, dateAdd(mi, @intervall, @tmpTime))
 set @tmpTime = dateAdd(mi, @intervall, @tmpTime)
END

/* Get data */
select l.StartTime, l.EndTime, sum(subTotal) from @SalesTable as SalesTable 
    join @lookUp as l on SalesTable.SaleDate >= l.StartTime and SalesTable.SaleDate < l.EndTime
    group by l.StartTime, l.EndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

In my query, I'm assuming one datetime field named date. This will give you all the groups starting at whatever datetime you give it to start with:

```
SELECT 
  ABS(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date, '2011-08-01 00:00:00') / 30)) AS GROUPING
  , SUM(subtotal) AS subtotals 
FROM 
  Receipts 
GROUP BY 
  ABS(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date, '2011-08-01 00:00:00') / 30))
ORDER BY
  GROUPING
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use the proper datatypes for your data.  In the case of your date/time columns, it's best to store them as (preferrably UTC zoned) timestamps.  This is especially true in that some times don't exist for some dates (for some timzones, hence UTC).  You will want an index on this column.

Also, your date/time range isn't going to give you what you want - namely, you're missing anything exactly on the hour (because you use a strict greater-than comparison).  Always define ranges as 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive' (so, `time >= '07:00:00' AND time < '07:30:00'`).  This is especially important for timestamps, which have an additional number of fields to deal with.

Because mySQL doesn't have recursive queries, you're going to want a couple of extra tables to pull this off.  I'm referencing them as 'permanent' tables, but it would certainly be possible to define them in-line, if necessary.

You're going to want a Calendar table.  These are useful for a number of reasons, but here we want them for their listing of dates.  This will allow us to show dates that have subtotals of 0, if necessary.  You're also going to want a value of times in half-hour increments, for the same reasons.

This should allow you to query your data like so:

```
SELECT division, COALESCE(SUM(subtotal), 0)
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMP(calendar_date, clock_time) as division
      FROM Calendar
      CROSS JOIN Clock
      WHERE calendar_date >= DATE('2011-09-10') 
      AND calendar_date < DATE('2011-09-11')) as divisions
LEFT JOIN Sales_Data
ON occurredAt >= division 
AND occurredAt < division + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
GROUP BY division
```

([Working example on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2718d6/12/0), which uses a regular `JOIN` for brevity)

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution too and posting it here for reference should anyone stumble upon this. Groups by half hour intervals.

```
SELECT SUM(total), time, date
FROM tableName
GROUP BY (2*HOUR(time) + FLOOR(MINUTE(time)/30))
```

Link for more info
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#106